# ASP.NET - unable to find view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is a long-standing issue with ASP.NET MVC not properly handling URL routes if there are forward slashes as a parameter even if they are URL encoded.

Example:
On a default install, go to this URL (adjusting ports as needed)

```
http://localhost:11541/Token/Create?
callback=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a11491%2ftoken%2fcreatetoken%2fAddPrivateValues
```

Notice that the Controller is "Token" and "Create" is the method to be called.  This is the error I get:

```
 The view 'http://localhost:11491/token/createtoken/AddPrivateValues' or
 its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
 locations. The following locations were searched:
 ~/Views/Token/http://localhost:11491/token/createtoken/AddPrivateValues.aspx
 ~/Views/Token/http://localhost:11491/token/createtoken/AddPrivateValues.ascx
 ~/Views/Shared/http://localhost:11491/token/createtoken/AddPrivateValues.aspx
 ~/Views/Shared/http://localhost:11491/token/createtoken/AddPrivateValues.ascx
```

Notice that it's calling "CreateToken/AddPrivateValues".  This is wrong.  It should be calling Token.Create.

This issue appears to have been broken since 2009 (according to prior S.O. research) so I'm not holding my breath.  I just need to fix this and move it to Azure.

I tried adding a {*id} route to my controller, but that doesn't work because there are many forward slashes.  The [only way to fix this is to disable this parsing in the machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656542.aspx)  (web.config WILL NOT WORK)

**Question**

How do I set this property in Windows Azure, without using RDP so that the permissions on Web.config are as secure and locked down as they were before I attempted to do this?

Comment: are you using azure web sites or vms?

Comment: @DanielA.White  I haven't decided on which approach I'm going for long term, but initially Web Sites.

Comment: you can't change the machine.config for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to replicate your issue on a clean deployment of an MVC 4 project. How are you trying to pass the callback parameter back to your view (if at all).  If you are using

```
return View(callback);
```

This would be why it is failing, because it is interpreting the string variable as a view name.  Try either storing it in a view bag or encapsulating it within a view model.  As a side note, I know that passing parameters with slashes seems to work in all MVC versions since on the Account/Login controller action you can send a returnUrl without issue.

Below is my configuration, let me know if I have deviated anywhere from your setup.

**Route Config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    //Changed default route to allow me to only have to create one controller
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Token", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Token Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create(string callback)
    {
        @ViewBag.Item = callback;
        return View();
    }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@ViewBag.Item
```

My URL: `http://localhost:11319/Token/Create?callback=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a11491%2ftoken%2fcreatetoken%2fAddPrivateValues`

**My Create Page Results**

```
<h2>Create</h2>

http://localhost:11491/token/createtoken/AddPrivateValues


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent, I made a dumb mistake and was troubleshooting the wrong thing.  Thank you